# PySpark: How to count the number of distinct values from two columns?

Tags: pyspark

I have a DataFrame with two columns, `id1, id2` and what I'd like to get is to **count** the number of distinct values of these two columns. Essentially this is `count(set(id1+id2))`.

How can I do that with PySpark?

Thanks!

Please note that **this isn't a duplicate** as I'd like for PySpark to calculate the `count()`. Of course it's possible to get the two lists `id1_distinct` and `id2_distinct` and put them in a `set()` but it doesn't seem to me the proper solution when dealing with big data and it's not really in the PySpark spirit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two columns into one using `union`, and get the `countDistinct`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cnt = df.select('id1').union(df.select('id2')).select(F.countDistinct('id1')).head()[0]
```